# Q: How to insert elements into a vector to call them later?

Tags: c++, vector

I wrote the next code, but it is wrong, since the `nodelinks` vector is empty, and I would like to include in it next elements: `src, dest, mins, maxs` to be call them later in another file.

```
std::vector<const Vector *> ServerDLL::GetNodeLinks() const
{
    std::vector<const Vector *> nodelinks;
    if (!WorldGraph) {
        return nodelinks;
    }

    const int count = *reinterpret_cast<int *>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(WorldGraph) + offm_cLinks);
    uintptr_t link = *reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t *>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(WorldGraph) + offm_pLinkPool);
    entvars_t *linkent = *reinterpret_cast<entvars_t**>(reinterpret_cast<Vector *>(link + offm_vecLinkEnt));

    std::vector<const Vector *> src;
    std::vector<const Vector *> dest;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        src.push_back(reinterpret_cast<Vector *>(link + offm_vecSrcNode + offm_vecOrigin));
        dest.push_back(reinterpret_cast<Vector *>(link + offm_vecDestNode + offm_vecOrigin));
        link += size_CLink;
    }

    Vector mins, maxs, origin;

    mins = linkent->mins;
    maxs = linkent->maxs;
    origin = linkent->origin;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        mins[i] += origin[i];
        maxs[i] += origin[i];
    }

    return nodelinks;
}
```

Comment: In the code presented, there is no insertion to `nodelinks`, thus it will be empty.

Comment: I want to insert to `nodelinks` next elements as I said: `src, dest, mins, maxs` to call them later in another file, to make it clearer, here is a functions from the tool for which I am write a code, as you can see it is to use two vectors in both cases: 

https://github.com/YaLTeR/BunnymodXT/blob/master/BunnymodXT/triangle_utils.hpp#L16-L18

It's a one examples of a function that how I'm going to call these vectors via `TriangleUtils`:

https://github.com/YaLTeR/BunnymodXT/blob/routes-scripts/BunnymodXT/triangle_drawing.cpp#L295-L313

Comment: I want to be end up in total with a next result: https://pastebin.com/T4iewfev